# Django EmailField accepts any value (including blank)

Tags: python, django, emailfield

Having this Django model:

```
class Subscriber(models.Model):
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True, blank=False)
```

I do not face any exceptions when creating a Subscriber with empty email:

```
>>> Subscriber.objects.create(email='')
<Subscriber: Subscriber object>
```

Interesting is that for the second time it will raise the IntegrityError:

```
>>> Subscriber.objects.create(email='')
...
IntegrityError: column email is not unique
```

So it seems to validate for integrity, but neither for email format nor for blank entries. How do I have the email validated?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The parameter `blank` is used from the form, it's not enforced at database level

From the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/models/fields/#blank)

> Field.blank If True, the field is allowed to be blank. Default is
>   False.
>
> Note that this is different than null. null is purely
>   database-related, whereas blank is validation-related. If a field has
>   blank=True, form validation will allow entry of an empty value. If a
>   field has blank=False, the field will be required.

Indeed the [validator documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/validators/#how-validators-are-run) says that

> Note that validators will not be run automatically when you save a model

to enforce that you have to use the [full_clean()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.full_clean) method.

The error is thrown because you are trying to insert two times the empty string and you have
the unique constraint on the field.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, now I see why IntegrityError is thrown, however I still do not get why no validation errors are thrown. I've edited my question to be more specific.

Comment: @VadimTikanov Because as I already wrote, the validators are ran only from the forms not from the model itself. I update the answer with reference to documentation.

Comment: I used this reference: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/instances/#validating-objects. Links seem to be dead in this post.

Answer (score -1):

you got to validate your e-mail field with a built in email-validator like this

```
from django.core.validators import validate_email
```

and declare your e-mail field in this way

```
email = models.EmailField(unique=True, validators=[validate_email,])
```

this way it will validate your e-mail field with a built in regular expression

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. With `blank=False`, the field validator should reject it regardless of whether it is a valid e-mail address.

Comment: you're not passing blank if you do `type('')` it returns `str` however a blank field should be None its an empty string you are declaring as email not blank.

Comment: Actually, `str('')` is still a blank `str`, rather than `None`. However, this doesn't change the fact that checking whether it is a valid e-mail address is different from verifying it isn't a blank string.

Comment: why dont you let the validator take care of the validation it will not match empty strings for sure you can see the regex used [here](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.5.1/django/core/validators.py#L81)

Comment: I imported validate_email, added it to EmailField arguments and run migration. However I can still create Subscriber with email = '' or email = 'aa'. Should I also call the validation method somewhere in the view?

Comment: @VadimTikanov even I am having the same problem